# Manipulating the JSON response of an API call, composed by various entities

Tags: symfony, php-8

I am creating an API that will provide data to a CMS, which will handle managing all orders for my e-commerce in Symfony 6.

I have primarily 7 entities: Address, Carrier, Customer, OrderDetail, OrderProducts, Orders, Product.

Each entity has its own endpoint, but I would like to create an endpoint that provides data from all the entities in a single API call (in some cases, I will need all properties of the entity, and in others, only some properties).

The goal of this single API call is to provide data to the CMS dashboard.

As in the picture, there are various data provided by the different entities, ex:

[image]

What is the best way to manipulate the JSON response inside Controller? Should I do everything through the Orders repository (with all the join between the entity's tables)? Use DTOs? What is the best approach?

There is a lot of data, as the default call will provide data of the orders of the last 6 months.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the modification you're doing. But I'd say this :

- If there are filters applied to the resulting values after modification : try to do it in the query itself, it will make the filtering easier.
- If the modifications are minor, doing it in the query might save you a tiny bit of performance (basically nothing) while keeping the query readable (or not much worse).
- If the modification are not minor (even just "medium"), do it in Php. It will be MUCH easier to update and to understand. Where, is kinda a matter of preference. I think some people would say "if you doubt, do it in a service". But not in the controller.
- Some people think that it's a bad thing to operate with entities, and that DTOs are always the way to go. Because you control more precisely what's in it, nothing is unpredictable. However, if you keep both entites, and DTOs, it makes the code more complex. Personally, I don't do it. But you can.

Understand that what you're asking is pretty subjective.

Comment: Hi FTW, thank you for your point of view. That's is very useful.